# Can I implement Shedlock for the run method implemented by the runnable interface

Tags: spring-boot, runnable, shedlock

I have a scheduler task created using Scheduled Future and Task scheduler. the scheduled task is basically a new class which implements runnable and used run method of the runnable interface. My doubt is can I use Shedlock on the run() function. Are there any problems in doing so

Comment: Scheduler.schedule(new TestClass,crontrigger)

Test class implements Runnable
//Shedlock here possible?
@Override
void run(){}

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts of the documentation you may find interesting. [TaskScheduler proxy](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock#taskscheduler-proxy) and if it does not halp, you can always fall back to [manual integration](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock#locking-without-a-framework).